# Event missing at beginning of week on Fullcalendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, timezone, fullcalendar

I have a Rails 3 App with Events stored in my database (timezone offset +2:00) that are displayed on fullcalendar.

My issue: all Events starting on monday between 0:00am and 2:00am are only displayed half a second before they disappear. Those Events are loaded correctly from the database as I can find them in the json object returned to fullcalendar. The Problem only occurs on Heroku production - I guess because they are located in a different timezone than me.

Already tried ignoreTimezone true/false but didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the ignoreTimezone to true, it only means that the events will use the timeZone of the browser. Check if this is your problem.

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/ignoreTimezone/